# Get Text From All Push Notifications Sent to App

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, swift3, ios10

Hey guys I did some searching online and didn't come up with much but I am looking to get all of the active notifications sent to my app since the last time I opened it. I found a lot of code with getting information from the notification the user opens the app with but that won't work since I want to be able to access all three notifications my app has instead of just the one I use to open it.

Now I was wondering if this was stored in a variable I can access from AppDelegate or if there is a delegate method I can add to AppDelegate that will be ran anytime a push notification is sent to my app even if my app has been killed and is not in the background.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: push notifications are best effort. They may not be delivered and you cannot acces notifications that were delivered while your app want running that the user didn't tap. When yo app launches the first thing it should do is query your backend for any data/updates it needs

Comment: Thanks thats what I working on now. I just figured I'd ask in case it could save me some time rather than adding more stuff to my table.